# How to use latex create "Microsoft" in my document?

Tags: latex

I was trying to type "Microsoft" with Latex,
the command I used was:
\textsc{Microsoft Office}

But this attempt would be all capital words.
Would anyone provide me with some advice?
Thank you!

Comment: There's an entire [stackexchange dedicated to all questions about TeX and LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/). You should ask your question over there

Comment: Ohh okay, sorry about this mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
\textsc{Microsoft Office}
```

use

```
\text{Microsoft Office}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give a try. Thanks!